# At what point does a browser throw and insecure content warning on an SSL site

Tags: javascript, html, ssl, warnings

Let me preface this with the situation, I am working in a shared environment with an website builder tool. I am trying to make the site load with https. I have the redirect done and it works, sort of, it gives me a warning about some page content wasn't loaded securely. There is no way in the tool to switch to all https links. I know relative links load with whatever protocol the main page used but the hard coded ones (the ones I cannot change without creating a disconnect between the browser and the builder and/or more work for me every publish) I am going to write some JavaScript to place in the header to run when the document loads to search and replace every instance of http to https.

My question is this does the browser wait for the page to load and then start running line by line before it flagging the first instance of a non https src or href or does it wait till all of the content loads and runs and then flags.

My thinking is if it runs the script first then i can place it in the header and be fine since the code is executed very near the top by order of operations.

Comment: It probably throws the warnings as soon as it starts thinking about initiating the HTTP requests, and for things like `<img>` and `<iframe>` that's going to happen as the elements are parsed. I'm guessing however.

Comment: A guess here as well, but as soon as the page has to reach for anything http:// (img, iframe, javascript, css, etc) it would lose its secure enviornment.

Comment: @Blake, that's what I am hoping for because I can place the scrip in there and it will run before anything else.

Comment: Is there any way you could pull the source in php, replace the http with https, then send it to the browser?

Comment: if the http:// links are relative, you can likely use a <base href=https://...> tag to fix your problem. if they are absolute URLs, you are going to have to get hacky to stop the page. or, can't you just use js in the <head> to set if(String(location).slice(0,5)=="http:"){ location.href='https://...';} ?

Comment: @Blake, No unfortunately there are very few people with that access and I would be more likely to hit the jackpot twice in the lottery than achieve that.

Comment: @dandavis, that may be what I do, another problem is I may not be able to include jquery either as it breaks one of the two tools i am working with (need to see if it breaks the other...)

Answer (score 0):

I just instituted SSL and found different browsers pick decidedly different points to both block content and devalue a page's posted security rating.

First, all embedded content calling http broke when I instituted SSL:

Firefox 41 0 01 picks up this mixed content and blocks it.

Chrome  45.0.2454.101 picks up and blocks the same mixed content.

Replacing http with https in my embedded content solves this.

Chrome 45.0.2454.101 at that point presents the page as "green lock" SSL.

Firefox 41 0 01 STILL picks up mixed content and does not block the embedded content, but refuses to certify the page as SSL secure. It provides the content without user changing the security setting and allowing unsecured content!

The FF console picks up a call out of what I assume is the embedded java for the embedded google map calling out, in my case to gstatic. It is calling an unsecured connection for an image file over http.

Specifically, FF console names "http://www.gstatic.com/gmeviewer/images/no_results-000.png" as the culprit.

Chrome console does not name this same call as offending SSL security when running the same page.

So, the answer to the question appears to be "at very different points," as I run the same page through these two different browsers and have very different results.

This is driving me crazy. I am very much more a creator of content than code. I would say that this interesting situation begs the next question, which would be,
"how can we get consistent page security through different browsers with the same page?"

Specifically, how can FF be made to display google embedded map content without breaking SSL and freaking out site admin and users?

Chrome displays exactly the same content as fully secure...

And... you guys here have been solving problems for me for five years now, great discussions here, thanks, and I hope my first participation is correct and helpful to answer and further clarify the question.

Comment: You might need to look to see if the embedded tool making that call has patches; ideally it wouldn't be calling out w/o SSL when loaded on a page containing SSL. Also, is the embedded content actually Java, or JavaScript? I'm guessing the latter, because no one uses Java in the browser anymore...